# Build body string

Tags: r, string

I am looking to build a body string as described below.

**Question:**

How can I achieve same result assuming that key value pairs is fetched from a list and key value pairs are 3 or more?

**Note:**

Some characters are only set once e.g. square brackets, and that the colon is used once per key value pair.

The content and key-value pair are only to describe the structure, the final solution will have other values, e.g epic = sweden, currency = USD, etc.

**Current ideas for solving the issue:**

Handle the data in 3 steps.

1) Each key and value needs to have escaped quotation.

2) Each key-value-pair should have colon as separator.

3) The complete string should be wrapped with curly brackets.

4) The last key-value-pair should not end with comma.

```
# Characters for building string.

curly_bracket_left  <- "{"
curly_bracket_right <- "}"
colon               <- ": "
comma               <- ", "

escaped_quotation   <- "\""

# Key-value-pairs data.

key_title_1         <- "epic"
value_title_1       <- "sweden"

key_title_2         <- "currency"
value_title_2       <- "SEK"

# Build string.

string <- paste0(
    curly_bracket_left,

        escaped_quotation,
        key_title_1,
        escaped_quotation,
    colon,

        escaped_quotation,
        value_title_1,
        escaped_quotation,
    comma,

        escaped_quotation,
        key_title_2,
        escaped_quotation,
    colon,

        escaped_quotation,
        value_title_2,
        escaped_quotation

    curly_bracket_right
)

print(string)
```

Outcome (as expected):

```
[1] "{\"epic\": \"sweden\", \"currency\": \"SEK\"}"
```

Wanted outcome when having 3 value-pairs:

```
[1] "{\"epic\": \"sweden\", \"currency\": \"SEK\", \"resolution\": \"minutes_5\"}"
```

Comment: @akrun. That is correct. The outcome is as expected. Question is how to expand the solution to handle more then 2 key-value-pairs. I will sometimes have 20-30 key-value-pairs.

Comment: Currently the solution is created in Global.env, for test purpose, but I plan to move it (when working) to R R6 as a part of a class that will be instantiated to create an object. My understanding is that an R6 object is basically an environment structure that is added as object to Global env.

Comment: The "key-X" and "value-Y" are only example of texts string. In the real solution I will have other names, e.g epic = sweden, currency = USD, etc. So the construction of text series will not solve the issue. Updated the question.

Comment: @akrun I updated the question with correct values in the key-value-pairs. It is of course very simple to just add the third key-value-pair manually and construct that part of string, but if the situation changes aving 20-30 key-value pairs it would require another logic to solve without having to much repetition in code.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there a particular reason you appear to be re-inventing [`rjson`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html), [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html), and [`RJSONIO`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html)?

Comment: @2evans Just need to have a detailed structure when sending in the body as part of a http request. I do use json in other parts of the code, but I was never able to add the escaped quotation as part of json solution.

Comment: r2evans Did some testing. Seems rjson can build the string from an R list. Jsonlite builds it also but I get some extra square bracket that would disqualify the string.

Comment: `jsonlite` is boxing things by default, but that can be changed with `jsonlite::unbox` or more broadly with `jsonlite::toJSON(list(a=1,b=2), auto_unbox=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collapse` arguement in `paste0` like so:

```
keys <- state.abb
vals <- state.name

# Characters for building string.

curly_bracket_left  <- "{"
curly_bracket_right <- "}"
colon               <- ": "
comma               <- ", "

escaped_quotation   <- "\""

paste0(
  curly_bracket_left,

  paste0(escaped_quotation,
         keys,
         escaped_quotation,

         colon,

         escaped_quotation,
         vals,
         escaped_quotation,
         collapse = comma
  ),

  curly_bracket_right
)

#output:
# [1] "{\"AL\": \"Alabama\", \"AK\": \"Alaska\", \"AZ\": \"Arizona\", \"AR\": \"Arkansas\", \"CA\": \"California\", \"CO\": \"Colorado\", \"CT\": \"Connecticut\", \"DE\": \"Delaware\", \"FL\": \"Florida\", \"GA\": \"Georgia\", \"HI\": \"Hawaii\", \"ID\": \"Idaho\", \"IL\": \"Illinois\", \"IN\": \"Indiana\", \"IA\": \"Iowa\", \"KS\": \"Kansas\", \"KY\": \"Kentucky\", \"LA\": \"Louisiana\", \"ME\": \"Maine\", \"MD\": \"Maryland\", \"MA\": \"Massachusetts\", \"MI\": \"Michigan\", \"MN\": \"Minnesota\", \"MS\": \"Mississippi\", \"MO\": \"Missouri\", \"MT\": \"Montana\", \"NE\": \"Nebraska\", \"NV\": \"Nevada\", \"NH\": \"New Hampshire\", \"NJ\": \"New Jersey\", \"NM\": \"New Mexico\", \"NY\": \"New York\", \"NC\": \"North Carolina\", \"ND\": \"North Dakota\", \"OH\": \"Ohio\", \"OK\": \"Oklahoma\", \"OR\": \"Oregon\", \"PA\": \"Pennsylvania\", \"RI\": \"Rhode Island\", \"SC\": \"South Carolina\", \"SD\": \"South Dakota\", \"TN\": \"Tennessee\", \"TX\": \"Texas\", \"UT\": \"Utah\", \"VT\": \"Vermont\", \"VA\": \"Virginia\", \"WA\": \"Washington\", \"WV\": \"West Virginia\", \"WI\": \"Wisconsin\", \"WY\": \"Wyoming\"}"
```